# How to read array elements into given object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am trying to read the array elements into the object as follows

```js
function points(games){
    let scoreBoard = {};
    for(let i = 0 ; i < games.length ; i++){
        let otherTeam = 0;
        let ourTeam = games[i][0];

        for(let j = 0 ; j < games[i].length; j++){
            otherTeam = games[i][j];
        }
        scoreBoard[ourTeam] = otherTeam;
    }
  return scoreBoard;
}

console.log(points(["1:0","2:0","3:0","4:0","2:1","3:1","4:1","3:2","4:2","4:3"]));
```

I want it to read in in the [x:y] format, i am missing something. Can you please help me ?

Comment: The reason is that you store it as object and you have duplicate key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you defined result as `let scoreBoard = {}`,it's an object and it stores values based on key,but you have multiple duplicate key,such as `4:1`,`4:2`,`4:3`,the key of them are `4`,so the last record will override the previous one.

In order to store all the scores,there are multiple options,such as make the key unique or using array to store it

```js
function points(games){
    let scoreBoard = [];
    for(let i = 0 ; i < games.length ; i++){
        let otherTeam = 0;
        let ourTeam = games[i][0];

        for(let j = 0 ; j < games[i].length; j++){
            otherTeam = games[i][j];
        }
        scoreBoard.push({[ourTeam]:otherTeam})
    }
  return scoreBoard;
}

console.log(points(["1:0","2:0","3:0","4:0","2:1","3:1","4:1","3:2","4:2","4:3"]));
```